# Python stops responding when I run cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv, video-tracking

My question is pretty simple. When I run a this piece of code, be it in VSCode, Terminal or Idle, Python stops responding. I can't find a solution for this anywhere.

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Does anyone know why this happens?

EDIT: People are saying that this code probably isn't the issue. I know that it is, as I ran it in the shell alone and got the exact same issue.

More info: I am on MacOS Big Sur Beta 4.

Comment: can you give the full code?

Comment: Did you run as an administrator?

Comment: run normally in console to see if you get any error message. You can also add `print(text)` in different places of code to see if it will display it - this way you will see what code is doing - or learn how to use debuger. And you should show rest of your code because problem can be in different place then you expect. This part of code should works without any problems.

Comment: @furas I updated my question with some more info that might be helpful

Comment: this command never made problem - so if you have problem then maybe problem is somewhere  deeper in code. `cv2` uses C/C++ library which may use other C/C++ libraries and it can makes problem. And it can makes problem only on your system. if you don't get any error messages then we don't have ideas what is problem and we can't help you.